# Issues installing Nuvola from Terminal or Package-Manager

Tags: release-freya, software-installation, nuvola

I'm trying desperately to install Nuvola Player 3 (package: nuvolaplayer3).
When trying to install from terminal I get:

```
E: Failed to fetch https://tiliado.eu/nuvolaplayer/repository/deb/pool/devel/n/nuvolaplayer3/nuvolaplayer3_3.1.0~201608141426.c7e45b4-0+1~trusty_amd64.deb  HttpError403

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

---

When I download the deb package and run it opens in software centre, gets most of the way and then says the below error.

```
Selecting previously unselected package libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 195971 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18_2.8.5+dfsg1-1~14.04~webkitteam1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.8.5+dfsg1-1~14.04~webkitteam1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37_2.8.5+dfsg1-1~14.04~webkitteam1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.8.5+dfsg1-1~14.04~webkitteam1) ...
Setting up libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.8.5+dfsg1-1~14.04~webkitteam1) ...
Setting up libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.8.5+dfsg1-1~14.04~webkitteam1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
dpkg: considering removing libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 in favour of nuvolaplayer3 ...
dpkg: no, cannot proceed with removal of libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (--auto-deconfigure will help):
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 depends on libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 (= 2.8.5+dfsg1-1~14.04~webkitteam1)
  libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 is to be removed.

dpkg: regarding .../nuvolaplayer3_0.20160613-Bundle1.for.Ubuntu.14.04.Trusty.Tahr_amd64.deb containing nuvolaplayer3:
 nuvolaplayer3 conflicts with libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18
  libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (version 2.8.5+dfsg1-1~14.04~webkitteam1) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /home/skywalker/Downloads/nuvolaplayer3_0.20160613-Bundle1.for.Ubuntu.14.04.Trusty.Tahr_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing nuvolaplayer3
```

---

I run `sudo apt-get remove libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64` due to the conflict but when I re-run the install after (either way) I get the same errors. I then find that the `libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64` is installed again.

I have tried rebooting and also doing sudo apt-get update but no change.

Any repository I try on the next doesn't add so I used the `tiliado-repositories_0.4.0-1_all.deb` file that installs them.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 2):

Nuvola Player developer here. If the installation via the Nuvola Player bundle fails because of conflicts, the recommended method is to use [Tiliado Repository Installer](https://tiliado.github.io/nuvolaplayer/documentation/3.0/install-ubuntu.html#installer).

Answer (score 1):

Follow these instructions
https://tiliado.eu/nuvolaplayer/repository/
but first run:

1. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
2. `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get upgrade -y`